# Tornado websocket server is getting slow

Tags: python, websocket, redis, tornado

I have a chat written on the Tornado socket server.
These are my critical parts of code.

```
class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
....
def __init__(self,*args):
    '''Initialization brukva client for the REDIS'''
    self.client = brukva.Client()
    self.client.connect()

def subscribe(self, room):
    '''Subscribing user to the channel on the REDIS server'''
    self.client.subscribe(room) 
    self.client.listen(self.redis_message)

def pass_message(self, message):
    self.write_message(json.dumps(message)) 


def redis_message(self, result):
    ''' recieving  message from redis server, 
        convertin it in json format 
        and sending it to the current chanel
    '''

    message = json.loads(result.body)
    try:
        self.write_message(json.dumps(message))
    except Exception, e:
        pass

def on_close(self):
      try:
        self.client.unsubscribe(self.room)
        self.client.disconnect()
    except:
        pass
```

As you can see I use REDIS server.
After connection from the javascript I fire a message to subscribe the Tornado instance to the REDIS channel and then pass all the messages that are meant for particular channel (room) to the javascript.

And  after server has been working for several days it becomes to works slowly and all the messages have delay for 3-5 sec but sometimes even stop working at all. There is no lack of memory. To eliminate that I should restart my tornado server.

Could someone tell me where the problem can be.

Thank you.

Comment: check Ram and CPU size for performance tuning . Code and resource bug are different!  Holding a class data for every user, isn't good choice(use user_id or hash_id).

Comment: It’s a memory leak. Check the process rss size